# Unable to Retrieve Custom Field Values in External WordPress Article Integration

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I am facing an issue where I cannot retrieve custom field values when integrating external systems with WordPress.

Here's a breakdown of the problem:

1. I have successfully integrated external systems with WordPress to fetch article content.
2. While I can retrieve the article content without any problems, I am unable to retrieve custom field values.
3. I have added custom fields using a plugin, and these fields are stored in the 'wp_postmeta' table in the WordPress database.
4. I have made several attempts to query and retrieve these custom field values using PHP and the WordPress database connection.

**One of my attempts is the code provided below:**

```php
function test_custom_database_query() {
    global $wordpress_db_conn; // Using the WordPress database connection object

    // Construct the query
    $sql = "SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_id = '1373'";
    
    // Execute the query
    $result = $wordpress_db_conn->query($sql);
    
    // Initialize the result variable
    $meta_value = '';
    
    if ($result) {
        $results = $result->fetch_object();
        if ($results) {
            $meta_value = unserialize($results->meta_value);
        }
    }
    
    return $meta_value;
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? Which plugin are you talking about? Why do you fetch by `meta_id`? And how are we supposed to help if half of the information is missing from your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [get_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) function.

The `get_post_meta` function allows you to retrieve metadata from a post based on its id and meta key.

```
get_post_meta($your_post_id, $your_meta_field_key);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already solved the problem.